# in pod file, how to add folder name with git repository and branch

Tags: git, cocoapods, bitbucket

pod 'vfile', :git => 'https://bitbucket.org/vfile/api' , branch:"test"

By using above command in pod file we need to fetch file from account folder / directory.

Please help me here.

Comment: `:branch => 'myBranchName'` It should have the same nomenclature as `:git =>`. For the git address, check on BitBucket, if you want to download/clone it, you should find your repo the link/path there.